# How to make desktop application with database, that will be runed by other people on different computers?

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio

For example I want to make program , where people create user for them-selfs and saves some notes for that user . On my computer I have created database named noteapp , and two tables , users and notes . I think the details of code and table columns is not necessary in this question. In my computer this program works. I create one user for me and save notes in it . it goes to database noteapp. but if I will send this program to someone else , it will not work . what should I do ? the database is not one for all people . every computer must have it's own database named noteapp stored as file in computer. what i should do ? i dont know from what should I start. Some people didn't understand me and said that I must install mysql server on other computer to run this program . but it is not one other computer. It will be on hundreds of other computers. Like usual desktop programs that we download from internet . thank you 
P.S.I work with visual studio 2010, mysql workbench 6.0. c++

Comment: Consider using sqlite for an integrated database solution. Databases are usually not suited for your usecase.

Comment: thank you Pharanix , now I know something about it . I will try ;)

Comment: @user3306372: btw... Your question sounded reasonable to me; sorry it got closed. I think you sufficiently explained that you had an app written and working, and you asked how to resolve a specific problem, having a database engine available on the client machine. The way that most developers satisfy that requirement is to use what's called an "embedded database". Good Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a local database engine for your app to run on the client, you could deploy an embedded database as part of your application.

If you've developed using MySQL, then it's probably easiest for you to use the MySQL embedded server library with your application.

Documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/libmysqld.html

---

MySQL isn't the only choice; there are lots of other embedded databases your application could use, such as SQL Server Compact (for the Windows environment), or SQLite (embedded in Google Android smartphones.)